# MySQL Join, even if there is not match ... Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, laravel-4

Here is my Laravel query:

```
$all_tags = DB::table('tags')
        ->join('products', 'tags.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftJoin('resources', 'tags.resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
        ->where('tags.user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('tags.id as tag_id', 'tags.serial_number', 'tags.pin_number', 'tags.expiry_date', 'tags.active as tag_active', 'tags.activation_date', 'products.name', 'products.image', 'resources.name as resource_name')
        ->get();
```

The problem is, sometimes there is no matching `product` and sometimes there is no matching `resource` ...

How do I deal with the "select" statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the tags to be returned even in the case when there are no matching products and no matching resources, you need to use a left join on both the products and the resources tables.